# How to create a PHPDocX-generated Word file that contains styled text with inline HTML

Tags: php, html, text-formatting, phpdocx

I'm using PHPDocX, and I want to create a Word file from a bunch of text that both contains inline HTML tags (e.g., `<b></b>`) and that needs to be styled (e.g., be justified, have the font set, etc.).

I've tried using the `addText` method, but then all the HTML tags show up literally. I then tried using the `embedHTML` method, but it seems like there is no way to style the text further when that method is used.

Ideally, I'd like to use `addText`, but at the same time, have the inline HTML tags render the text accordingly. Is there any way to do this? Thank you.

---

**Edit**: I had considered breaking the text apart on the HTML tags, and then using the `addText` method multiple times per text block to style the text accordingly, but the problem with that method is that every time I use `addText`, a new paragraph element is create. If it were possible to append multiple pieces of text with `addText` and have them all be in the same paragraph, then I think it would be possible.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question. "Example #2" on the following page of the official documentation explains how to underline / make bold only certain parts of the text within a paragraph:
http://www.phpdocx.com/api-documentation/word-content/add-paragraph-text-Word-document-with-PHP

The main idea is that the `$text` argument for `addtext` needs to be an array with the text stored in the `'text'` key.